# jQuery toggle() doesn't work inside included (using PHP) code.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following code defined in order to hide certain elements of a list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".done").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Basically, any < button > element being clicked will execute the toggle() function on any element with the "done" class. I know this works, because it works on some of my buttons. I have a page made up of several included files (using PHP include()). Usually, the javascript works in and out of these included files, but for some reason if I put a button inside one of them, it doesn't work - the function only works for buttons placed on the document where the script is defined. Is this always  the case, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

to:

```
$("button").live('click', function(){
```

This will make the event bind to any button, no matter when they are added.  If you are using `.live`, then you don't need it inside a `$(document).ready(` block, as `.live` will add the event when the element is added.

Answer (score 5):

try using jQuery [live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$("button").live('click', function(){
    $(".done").toggle();
});
```